# Does "all this" mean "you two" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

GRETEL

Hey no joking, I’m impressed!
That’s not something I’d have guessed.
Now let’s see you keep that smile,
Trying out a harder style.

With your head you nick nick nick,
With your fingers tick tick tick.
One by here,
One by there,
Round you go without a care.

HANSEL

With my head I nick nick nick,
With my fingers tick tick tick.
One by here,
One by there,
Round without a care.

GRETEL speaks
SHHH! Look busy. Here’s mother.

**MOTHER**

**What’s all this horsing around?** Stop it at once. Playing is for rich kids! We’re too poor. There will be no supper until you finish your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression **all this** is often used in informal English to parcel up a group of activities as one thing. In this sentence, it relates to relates to "[horsing around](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/horse-around?q=horsing%20around)", which means behaving in a silly way.

Here is another example, where it relates to **trouble**:

> I claim today that they were the cause of **all this** trouble.. - Death's Door - Steve Lehto, 2006